# MATLAB create constant spacing between numbers on same line

Tags: matlab, alignment, printf, spacing

Good morning,

I'm sure there's a built in function but I can't find it. I want to create static positioning for information being sent to a text document in MATLAB. For example:

```
height          weight          age          favorite number
------------------------------------------------------------     
60              140             24           9
30              45              3            10000000
48              100             9            19
9               7               1            1
```

currently, i'm just doing an fprint call with padded spaces to get it lined up, but the issue arises where having different length numbers causes the alignment to be off, like so:

```
height          weight          age          favorite number
------------------------------------------------------------     
60              140             24           9
30              45             3           10000000
48              100             9           19
1              7              1           1
```

Thanks in advance.

here's an example script that'll show what I mean:

```
fid1 = fopen('stackoverflowtest', 'w');
if fid1 < 3,
  error('ERROR');
end;

fprintf(fid1, 'height          weight          age          favorite number \n');
fprintf(fid1, '------------------------------------------------------------ \n');

height = 0;
weight = 10;
age = 100;
number = 3;

for i = 1:100
    fprintf(fid1, "%d              ', height);
    fprintf(fid1, "%d              ', weight);
    fprintf(fid1, "%d          ', age);
    fprintf(fid1, "%d \n", number);

    height = height + 3;
    weight = weight + 6;
    age = age - 1;
    number = number + 23;
end
```

Comment: Could you show us your code snippet, just so we know what you're working with?

Comment: I added an example script keeping with the same style of my original example as I cannot provide the exact code but the concept is identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [`fprintf` format specification](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#input_argument_d119e322652), for example `%-15d`.

Here, the `-` is a flag which specifies left justification, and the `15` specifies how much space to leave around the representation.

We can reproduce your example with

```
A = [60 140 24 9
     30 45  3  10000000
     48 100 9  19
     9  7   1  1];
fprintf('height          weight          age          favorite number \n'),...
fprintf('------------------------------------------------------------ \n'),...
fprintf('%-15d %-15d %-12d %-15d \n',A')
```

which displays

```
height          weight          age          favorite number 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
60              140             24           9               
30              45              3            10000000        
48              100             9            19              
9               7               1            1
```

**EDIT:** You can store this data as a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html):

```
height = A(:,1)
weight = A(:,2);
age  = A(:,3);
favourite_number = A(:,4);
tab1 = table(height, weight, age, favourite_number);
disp(tab1);
```

This prints to screen

```
height    weight    age    favourite_number
______    ______    ___    ________________

60        140       24         9           
30         45        3     1e+07           
48        100        9        19           
 9          7        1         1
```

but I'm not sure how to save this representation to a file.

Comment: thanks, I knew there was some built in justification that could be applied I just didn't know what to look for to find it